# configs/nuttx_px4fmu-v2_default

Tags: ros, px4, catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the tutorials from https://pixhawk.org/dev/ros/sitl and in the end when I did catkin_make, i got the following error. I did not change any files, all I did was follwed that tutorial. Please help!!

```
CMake Error at Firmware/CMakeLists.txt:158 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    configs/nuttx_px4fmu-v2_default


CMake Error at Firmware/CMakeLists.txt:171 (message):
  configs/nuttx_px4fmu-v2_default must implement px4_os_prebuild_targets


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/zee/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/zee/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

Additional Details:

My Firmware/CMakeLists.txt file includes these lines in the line 158 and 171

```
151) # switch to ros CMake file if building ros
152) if (${OS} STREQUAL "ros")
153)    include("cmake/ros-CMakeLists.txt")
154) else()  # otherwise use the rest of this file
155) 
156) list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
157) set(config_module "configs/${CONFIG}")
158) include(${config_module})
159) 
160) # cmake modules
161) include(ExternalProject)
162) 
163) # require px4 module interface
164) set(px4_required_interface
165)    px4_os_prebuild_targets
166)    px4_os_add_flags
167)    )
168) 
169) foreach(cmd ${px4_required_interface})
170)    if(NOT COMMAND ${cmd})
171)    message(FATAL_ERROR "${config_module} must implement ${cmd}")
172)    endif()
173) endforeach()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220196/configs/nuttx_px4fmu-v2_default/) by [zshn25](https://answers.ros.org/users/24962/zshn25/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-10-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Issue for this thread https://github.com/PX4/Firmware/issues/3099#issuecomment-179081973

Just download the updated firmware and it works perfectly fine.

---

Originally posted by [zshn25](https://answers.ros.org/users/24962/zshn25/) with karma: 21 on 2016-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try to use:

```
catkin_make --cmake-args -DCONFIG=ros_sitl_simple
```

instead of 'catkin_make'

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2015-12-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AloshkaD](https://answers.ros.org/users/27344/aloshkad/) on 2016-07-08**:
That didn't work!